# Keep getting redirected to login page even after successfull login in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application that use ASP.NET Core Identity. I have decorated one controller with `[Authorize]` and when I try to access that page I get redirected to my login page where I login, so far so good. The issue is that when I am redirected back to the same page that is decorated with `[Authorize]` I'm then redirected back to the login page again. Why is that? Here is my program.cs file...

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


        builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        builder.Services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opts => opts.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10));

        builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true; 
        });


        var app = builder.Build();


        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthenticationCheck();


        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
    }
```

Here is my login controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser appUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);
            if (appUser != null)
            {
                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(appUser, login.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                    return Redirect(login.ReturnUrl ?? "/");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id = 1 });
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(login.Email), "Login Failed: Invalid Email or password");
        }
        return View(login);
    }
```

And my controller that need the user to be logged in..

```
        [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy()
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        string message = "Hello " + user.UserName;
        return View((object)message);
        //return View();
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the controller be decorated with `[Authorize]` rather than `[Authenticate]`? What is `[Authenticate]`?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong.... it is [Authorize] on the controller but the issue is the same

Answer (score 0):

That call to `app.UseAuthentication()` must occur before `app.UseAuthorization()`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication)

> Calling `UseAuthentication` registers the middleware that uses the previously registered authentication schemes. Call `UseAuthentication` before any middleware that depends on users being authenticated.

Find an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services) which shows below code fragment and mention.

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

> `UseRouting`, `UseAuthentication`, and `UseAuthorization` must be called in the order shown in the preceding code.